# How the SSL/TLS CA certificate will update in my device if it is renewed from server maintainer?

Tags: ssl, webserver, website, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

How the SSL/TLS CA certificate will update if it renewed from website maintainer.

Actually Rooot CA certificate expiry for 1 or 2 years, after that server maintainer should go to certificate Authority renewal for further validity, so in this condition **how my client device update new renewed certificate?**

I could get some answers from websites like if the certificate expire then we will get some warning message and data communication also plain text , so that it is vulnerable for man in the middle attack.

will it be update new certificate automatically or need to place the certificate manually in client location?

Thanks!

Comment: What client device are you talking about? How is the certificate verification implemented in this client device?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is never renewed automatically, and the renewal
usually requires payment (renewal is usually less costly than
the original certificate).

It's up to you to renew the certificate and install the new one
in the same way as you installed the original one,
thus replacing the old certificate.

Just to note that an expired certificate may under the
right conditions still be usable and accepted by software
(with mostly just a warning message).